# Why won't Azure OCR code loop through media?

Tags: azure, ocr

I'm trying to get a project going where I can extract text from JPGs, PNGs, and PDFs. [I found this article where someone made something similar](https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/4/28/image-processing-with-cognitive-services)

I tried following this person's guide and tried tying it to my Azure instance, but when I run the code (basically copied exactly what he did), I get an error of KeyError: 'regions'

Any idea what the issue may be? I have the error screenshot below, as well as the code (with my API key and endpoint removed.

[image: Error when running code]

[image: code being used for OCR with Azure]

Comment: I would start by looking into the `results` variable ? is there value returned there ?

Comment: For the second time now, an hour after I post my question on stack overflow I figure it out. It was using the wrong endpoint in the code....

Thank you Satya for the response. It is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So turns out I was just using the wrong end point in the code. I was copying what was given to me in Azure and not what the guy had in his video. Ooops